# Global Secondary Index DynamoDB empty value error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a string attribute that can be an empty value. And I want to set it as a Global Secondary Index. But it showed an error when I tried to perform **UpdateItemRequest** or **SaveTable** Context:

`Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: One or more parameter values are not valid. A value specified for a secondary index key is not supported. The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value. IndexName: .... IndexKey: ...`

What is wrong with my mindset or my settings? I'm new to DynamoDB and had a MongoDB base. If I don't use GSI for this attribute, how to perform a query on that attribute?

I tried

```
[DynamoDBIgnore] string property;
var operationConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig() { };
operationConfig.IsEmptyStringValueEnabled = true;
operationConfig.Conversion = DynamoDBEntryConversion.V2;
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Can you share how you are creating the table?

Comment: I created a base table with a hash key, and use the Object persistence model in .Net to save/load data .

Comment: Can you post the code that does that?

Answer (score 3):

This states that you are setting the value for your GSI PK to an empty string `""` which is not supported.

In order to overcome this, you simply remove any value from that attribute, i.e don't set it at all. This allows your index to become sparse in that it will only store data that has a key associated with it.

Comment: Hello, I am using .net DynamoDB SDK's latest version. I am trying to save a Document by DynamoDBContext.SaveAsync() .And It seems that [DynamoDBIgnore] Attribute doesn't work when I put it in a Global Secondary Index.

Comment: operationConfig.IsEmptyStringValueEnabled. Probably as a result of that line of code?

Comment: I tried to comment this line: 
`operationConfig.IsEmptyStringValueEnabled` and keep using DynamoDBEntryConversion.V2
and the result is the same.